# Wordpress - Users with contact form on profile

Tags: forms, user-registration, profiles, contact

I should build a site, where the users sign up and can create and customize a profile like a social media. But instead of adding friends to a friendlist (like fb ect.), all the sites should have a contact form from where the visitor could send them a request on email.

So basic requirments:
User login and registration,
Contact form on each user profile to contact the individual

How would you handle a job like that? Any smart plug-ins, that can help me on my way?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a question that can be answered on SO. How to build a website with X options is a very broad subject, even if in your option you supplied all the information needed to create this site, i still don't think a single answer will give you all you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I dont expect to get everything i am looking for, i am just looking for the easiest way. I know there are a lots of ways to get there, and that a one-size-fits-all option isn't possible. But all the contact forms i have worked with earlier only send mails to the website owner. So my biggest hurdle is how to add a form to a user profile, and send the mail to the profile onwer

Comment: I've built something along these lines.  I created an invite process where a user has the ability to input the email of the person they want to invite.  The user then receives the email and IF they already have an account, can accept, if they don't have an account they first register and then accept. I store the 'invite tokens' in a custom DB table and track when they were sent, to whom, whether they were accepted or declined, etc.  It wasn't easy as there are a lot of details.